# Is is possible to assign a "name" to the data I'm outputting from the database?

Tags: php, html

I want to assign a name to the answers I'm outputting from the database

I'm setting up a questionnaire/quiz with the questions and answers in the database.

PHP:

```
public function site() {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $generalSite = "SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE qid = 1 AND sub_answer IS NULL";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($generalSite);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $answer) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="$answer['answer']">'.$answer['answer'];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style='width: 100%; text-align: center; padding-top: 120px;'>
<p><?php echo $question->question1(); ?></p>
<p><?php echo $answer->site(); ?></p>
```

I'm hoping to make it something like this: `<p><input type="radio" name="head">Head</p>`

Comment: `echo '<input type="radio" name="' . strtolower($answer['answer']) . '">' . $answer['answer'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . strtolower($answer['answer']) . '">' . $answer['answer'];
```

In the comments by [showdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924299/showdev)